# Read multiple characters in char input and convert to double

Tags: java, char, sqrt

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    char ch;

    ch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("").charAt(0);

    if (Character.isLetter(ch))
    {
        System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
    }

    if (Character.isDigit(ch))
    {
        Math.sqrt(ch);
        System.out.println(ch);
    }

    if (Character.isWhitespace(ch))
    {
        int code = ch;
        System.out.println (code);
    }
}
```

If I input more than one character, it only recognises the first character. How do I make the program see multiple characters that a user inputs as a char?

Comment: `.charAt(0)` You are telling it to only take the first char.

Comment: How do I get it to take multiple characters?

Comment: Declare `ch` as a string and remove the `.charAt(0)`. However you will also need to add a loop to iterate over each of the caracter you received

Comment: @JM Do you want to treat each `character` differently and perform an `if` statement on each `character` separately ?

Comment: What this exercise should do, is basically this. A user inputs characters, if the character is a digit, it must be converted from a char to a double. From there it must be square rooted, so if I enter 16 for example, it should show 4 but it only sees the 1 and not the 6, that's my main problem @shashwat

Comment: @JM Last confirmation. If the input is `ab`, should It treat `a` and `b` separately, or together like the `16` you just mentioned ?

Comment: Like 16 @Shashwat

Comment: @JM Please check my Answer

Answer (score 0):

You are taking only the first `character` with this:-

```
 ch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("").charAt(0);
```

The `charAt(0)` gives you the `character` with the index of `0`, which is always the first character.

If you want to treat your `input` as a Whole and not only the First  character, try using a String as follows

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("");
```

Also note that your `Charater.isLetter(ch)` won't work now, as you can't do that with a `String`. However, you can convert the whole `String` to `UpperCase` if you want. Also, you can't easily look whether  `String` is a valid `Double` or not. It requires `exception handling` and may be confusing. I am including it anyway, so if you are confused,feel free to ask.

The Final Program looks like this:-

```
String s;
s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("");
try{
    double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
}catch(Exception e){
    //Not a Double as it comes inside catch
    //Therefore String must be empty or contain Characters

    //Checking for Empty

    if(s.trim().length()<1){
    //String is empty 
    //Do what you want
    System.out.println("String is whitespace");
    }else {
       //String must contain Characters.
       System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

**Please ask, if you are stuck at anything.**

Comment: Thanks for the help! Much appreciated! @Shashwat